# How to build a Docterine Inner Join Query in Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, dql

Im working on a Symfony project and I want to create Doctrine Query for this SQL.

USER table :
columns -
  NICK_NAME

REVIEWS table:
columns -
  USER_ID
,  REVIEW,
  CREATED_AT

Thank you

```
SELECT
`USER`.NICK_NAME,
REVIEWS.REVIEW,
REVIEWS.CREATED_AT
FROM
REVIEWS
INNER JOIN `USER` ON REVIEWS.USER_ID = `USER`.ID
WHERE
REVIEWS.MOVIE_ID = 625
GROUP BY
REVIEWS.USER_ID
```

I tried something like this

```
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->select("u.NICK_NAME,r.REVIEW,r.CREATED_AT")
            ->from('REVIEWS r')
            ->innerJoin('`USER` ON REVIEWS.USER_ID = `USER`.ID')
            ->where('REVIEWS.MOVIE_ID = 625')
            ->groupBy('REVIEWS.USER_ID');
```

and got this:

```
500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Exception Couldn't find class `USER`
```

Comment: You query will return indeterminate results for review columns because you are using group by with out any aggregate function in your query

Comment: but it makes no sense, because if I run that SQL it returns what I want. and I tried some DQL like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using complex DQL in Symfony you can use simple SQL.
Try this function in the controller where you want to run the DQL.

```
 function getUserReviews($params) {
        $query = "SELECT REVIEWS.REVIEW, `USER`.NICK_NAME, REVIEWS.CREATED_AT FROM REVIEWS INNER JOIN `USER` ON REVIEWS.USER_ID = `USER`.ID WHERE REVIEWS.MOVIE_ID ='".$params."'";
        return Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()->fetchAssoc($query);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You Should Specify Entity name not table name in DQL like this `YourBundleName:EntityName`

Use it like this:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->select("u.NICK_NAME,r.REVIEW,r.CREATED_AT")
            ->from('REVIEWS r')
            ->innerJoin('YourBundleName:EntityName ON REVIEWS.USER_ID = `USER`.ID')
            ->where('REVIEWS.MOVIE_ID = 625')
            ->groupBy('REVIEWS.USER_ID');
```

Alternative Solution if above solution doesn’t work:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
                ->select("u.NICK_NAME,r.REVIEW,r.CREATED_AT")
                ->from('REVIEWS r')
                ->innerJoin('YourBundleName:EntityName', 'USER_ID')
                ->where('REVIEWS.MOVIE_ID = 625')
                ->groupBy('REVIEWS.USER_ID');
```

If that doesn't work, use Inner join in following manner:

```
->InnerJoin('YourBundleName:Entity', '<alias>', Expr\Join::ON, $qb->expr()->eq('IDENTITY(<alias.<clummn_name>)', '<comapring_column>'))
```

inner Join from Doctrine2 Documentation:

Example -

```
$qb->innerJoin('u.Group', 'g', Expr\Join::WITH, qb->expr()->eq('u.status_id', '?1'))

$qb->innerJoin('u.Group', 'g', 'WITH', 'u.status = ?1')

$qb->innerJoin('u.Group', 'g', 'WITH', 'u.status = ?1', 'g.id')
```

innerJoin Method Prototype:

```
innerJoin($join, $alias, $conditionType = null, $condition = null, $indexBy = null);
```

Find More [Here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods)

Hope this will help you.